# SharePoint Dir() issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VBA code which counts any `.xl*` files at a specific path. This code works when running on a normal network drive.  However someone want to run the code on a network running SharePoint.  It's difficult for me to debug as I'm not on the SharePoint system and can't replicate the issue.  However the person says the code falls over when running the following line

```
FilesInPath = Dir(myPath & "*.xl*")
```

where `FilesInPath` is the number of file at the path myPath which have a `.xl*` extension and `myPath` is a filepath on the Sharepoint file system.  This works fine running on a non-SharePoint.

I guess the problem is with the Dir() element is there a SharePoint friendly equivalent?

Comment: (1) `Dir()` returns a string, not a number. (2) What do you mean by "SharePoint filesystem"? If you mean something like `https://server.name/SharePoint Name/Folder Name` then that's not really a filesystem, and `Dir()` won't work.

Comment: Thanks Alex, Any idea what would work?

Comment: I dont have an environement to test this out, but this link my be of use https://officeaccelerators.wordpress.com/2015/01/29/vba-code-to-download-list-of-files-and-folders-from-sharepoint/